# Qt GUI issue in RPI

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi, qtgui

I am new to QT and my task is to make GUI for Raspberry pi ( with Raspbian OS ) i have qt 4 installed in x86 machine and libs in RPI.
I am devloping application in my x86 and cross compiling on RPI .
Initaly i made a QT app and it was working on RPI but now the application is compiling for RPI but GUI is not proper in RPI which is perfectly working on host machine ( same code ),
I.e
1) I added a frames which is being seen in x86 machine but is not being seen in RPI,
2) I added a push buttons and they were priveously working (they were respomd
ing to clicking events ) but now they are not responding to clicks.

So what i tried is Re-flashed RPI with new Image( Raspbian OS) but still facing same issues .
So, Do anyone has an idea in which direction i need to dig ?
Please ask me if you need more information .
Any suggestons in this case would be appriceiable.
Thank You !!

Comment: Run your app from the console. Qt usually logs a few things if it thinks they are not what should be. Paste those contents here, it might help finding an answer. Despite that, I can't think of anything, sorry.

Comment: Thank You for your valuable response.
But as i said I’m new to QT and i don’t know much so could you Guide me how can i see log on Console .?

Comment: Just open the console (Gnome Terminal, Konsole, or whatever is your favorite console app) and run your Qt app. Nothing else needs to be done. Some messages may be printed once the app is run (or error messages if the app can not be executed). These are the messages we are looking for.